# Stop vis.js physics after nodes load but allow drag-able nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to draw a vis.js network diagram and have vis load and position the nodes.  I then want the physics to be disabled so the nodes can be moved by the user.  I have tried this but it is not working.

```
var options = {

    nodes: {
      borderWidth:4,
      size:60,
      color: {
        border: '#222222',
        background: 'grey'
      },
      font:{color:'black'}
    },
    edges: {
      arrows: {
        to:     {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1},
        middle: {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1},
        from:   {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1}
      },
      color: 'black'
    },

    { physics: enabled: false; };
```

Has anyone done this? if so can you provide an example or advice on best way to accomplish this.  I have also read the explanation located [here](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/161), but not being too familiar with java I can't figure the steps out.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After some more work and help from the vis.js developer here is the completed code, minus the json data and some options. The trick is to use the `"stabilizationIterationsDone"` event and disable physics:

```
 // create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {

    nodes: ...,
    edges: ...,

    physics: {
        forceAtlas2Based: {
            gravitationalConstant: -26,
            centralGravity: 0.005,
            springLength: 230,
            springConstant: 0.18,
            avoidOverlap: 1.5
        },
        maxVelocity: 146,
        solver: 'forceAtlas2Based',
        timestep: 0.35,
        stabilization: {
            enabled: true,
            iterations: 1000,
            updateInterval: 25
        }
    }
};

network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

network.on("stabilizationIterationsDone", function () {
    network.setOptions( { physics: false } );
});
```

Comment: Where exactly should the "stabilizationIterationsDone" be defined?

Comment: Works a treat however the arrows don't get moved to the nearest edge. Any idea how to allow this to occur after moving a box?

Comment: On moving the nodes around, it's not smooth, it's laggy. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you first want to let the network stabilize and only then disable physics? In that case you can load the Network with `physics` and `stabilization` enabled. Once the nodes are stabilized, the `stabilized` event is fired. Then you can disable the physics via `network.setOptions`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I have read this on the vis.js github site.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct would you mind providing an example?

Comment: On moving the nodes around, it's not smooth, it's laggy. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure this out and the code now looks like this

```
// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {

    nodes: {
      borderWidth:1,
      size:45,
      color: {
        border: '#222222',
        background: 'grey'
      },
      font:{color:'black',
       size: 11,
       face :'arial',
       },
    },

    edges: {

        arrows: {
            to:     {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1},
            middle: {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1},
            from:   {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1}
        },
        color: {
            color:'#848484',
            highlight:'#848484',
            hover: '#848484',
        },
        font: {
            color: '#343434',
            size: 11, // px
            face: 'arial',
            background: 'none',
            strokeWidth: 5, // px
            strokeColor: '#ffffff',
            align:'vertical'
        },
        smooth: {
            enabled: false, //setting to true enables curved lines
            //type: "dynamic",
            //roundness: 0.5
        },
    }
};

network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    network.setOptions({
            physics: {enabled:false}
    });
}
```

I had to move the `network.setOptions()` as shown in the new code and it is now working as desired.

Comment: On moving the nodes around, it's not smooth, it's laggy. Any idea how to fix that?