# vis.js physics - how to fix some nodes in place

Tags: javascript, vis.js

In my application, a graph is loaded initially with the one-net of a particular node.  The user can expand the graph by double-clicking any node to add its one-net.

The problem is that every time the user does that, the nodes all jump around, so it's confusing.  I don't want to just disable physics, because then the new nodes get jumbled on top of the old ones.  For lack of a better explanation, I want to freeze the existing nodes, only using physics to arrange the new nodes (and then freeze them before adding more).  I looked at [Stop vis.js physics after nodes load but allow drag-able nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403578/stop-vis-js-physics-after-nodes-load-but-allow-drag-able-nodes), but that doesn't solve my problem.

I'm pretty clueless about what the various options to the physics solving algorithms mean, and can't find a good description anywhere, so I wonder if there may be tweaks there that would help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can give some of your nodes a fixed `x` and `y` position. There are also methods like `getPositions()` and `storePositions()` to retrieve or set the positions after the first stabilization or something like that.

Comment: I've been having a conversation on the github forum as well.  I tried setting the positions to fixed after stabilization, and then the new nodes were placed on top of them.  I'm really feeling confused here.